# Cygwin: call to spawnvp causes non-console program to have a console window

Tags: cygwin

Here is a small program to reproduce the behavior using Cygwin 2.5.2, under Windows 7.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

int main(void)
{
   const char * const argv[] = {
     "c:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe",
     0
   };

   Sleep(5000);
   return spawnvp(_P_WAIT, argv[0], argv);
}
```

This is built as follows:

```
$ gcc -mwindows spawn.c -o spawn
```

**The good:** Correctly, this program does not start with a console window. We can navigate to its directory with Windows Explorer and launch it. Nothing appears on the screen as the program begins executing and reaches the `Sleep(5000)` statement.

**The bad:** After five seconds pass, the `spawnvp` call is executed, and the program gets a console window! Notepad launches and its window shows over top of this console window.

Can someone explain why, and how to make this go away? Only Notepad should show, not any spurious console window.

Of course, if we spawn a console program, *that* program should get its own console window. That's not the issue here; the *parent* is getting the unwanted window (and the child isn't a console program at all).

**Update:** I'm now rebuilding Cygwin, hoping to be able to add some debug print statements into the complicated guts underlying the `spawn*` functions, to see at which point the window appears.

Answer (score 2):

I tracked this down. All Cygwin `spawn*` and `exec*` calls go through `spawne` which relies on `child_info_spawn::worker` class member function, implemented in `winsup/cygwin/spawn.cc`.

This function contains the following:

```
  if (mode == _P_DETACH)
    c_flags |= DETACHED_PROCESS;
  else
    fhandler_console::need_invisible ();
```

The culprit is the call to this `fhandler_console::need_invisible` which allocates a console. For some reason Cygwin thinks that an invisible console window needs to be created if the calling application doesn't already have one. Unfortunately, the plans to create this invisible window don't pan out as planned; we get a visible window.

If I comment out this call to `need_invisible` and rebuild the Cygwin DLL, the problem goes away.